# XDocument descendant of descendants simple statement

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file with subelements of elements:

```
<Root>
     <Location>
         <DepartureBoundary>
            <DepartureBoundaryRadius>600</DepartureBoundaryRadius>
         </DepartureBoundary>
     </Location>
     <Location>
         <DepartureBoundary>
            <DepartureBoundaryRadius>600</DepartureBoundaryRadius>
         </DepartureBoundary>
     </Location>
</Root>
```

Currently, I am doing the following to access the value for DepartureBoundaryRadius:

```
XDocument locationsDoc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
DepartureLocationBoundaryRadius = null;
List<DepartureBoundaryRadius> radiusList = new List<DepartureBoundaryRadius>();

foreach (XElement locationElement in locationsDoc.Descendants("Root"))
{
    foreach (XElement locationSubElement in locationsDoc.Descendants("Location"))
    {
        foreach (XElement departureElement in locationsDoc.Descendants("DepartureBoundary"))
        {
             DepartureLocationBoundaryRadius =  departureElement.Element("DepartureRadius").Value));
             radiusList.Add(DepartureLocationBoundaryRadius);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this? I would rather assign the value of   DepartureLocationBoundaryRadius in one line or one statement -- especially since each Location has only one DepartureBoundaryRadius value. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `Elements` in your question . `Descendants` already gives what you want

```
var values = locationsDoc.Descendants("DepartureBoundaryRadius")
                          .Select(x => x.Value)
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: I got the following error when I put that statement in code:
Error 18 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it. DUH!

Answer (score 0):

```
 var list = xdoc.Document.Descendants("DepartureBoundaryRadius").Select(x=>x.Value);
```